# File size issue. while poi read write

Tags: java, excel, xls, apache-poi

I am using apache poi api to deal with my spread sheet files.
I have observed, if we try to edit an existing .xls file it size is not the same as if that same file (same data ) is written in one go.

Answer (score 3):

It is normal for an Excel spreadsheet to grow after being opened or edited.  When a spreadsheet is opened in Microsoft Excel the formulas are automatically calculated, so this increases the size of the file.  If a spreadsheet is opened by Apache POI it is up to the developer to call the ([FormulaEvaluator](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html)) to update all the values.  When a spreadsheet is read by Apache POI and the formulas have not been evaluated, formula answers may be invalid.

Comment: Well perhaps, you are may be true in a sense, but I think I have not clear the context or something. 

Actually the thing which bothered me is that, I am not using any formulas in the spread sheet and writing stings in the file. 

the only difference is that one file is created in first attempt (i.e. 100 records) where as another file with the same 100 records is created in two or three sessions (i.e. 50 + 50). 

although both files have identical records(without any formula). yet their size is different. 

I am using Apache POI for this.

Comment: `fileName = "poi-test2.xls";
File file=new File(fileName);
FileInputStream fileIn = null;
FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
HSSFSheet worksheet = null;
if(file.exists()){
 fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
 workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileIn);
 fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
}else{
 workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
 worksheet = workbook.createSheet(worksheetName);
 fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
 }
worksheet = workbook.getSheet(worksheetName);
int rowNo = worksheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
System.out.println(rowNo);`

Answer (score 3):

POI will always write out one record per cell

Excel, however, will sometimes bunch several similar sequential cells up into a single record. For example, if you have 3 cells in a row that are blank but styled, then excel will generate a [MulBlankRecord](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/MulBlankRecord.html) which holds all of them. For several cells in a row with simple numbers in them, excel uses a [MulRKRecord](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/MulRKRecord.html)

When POI reads in a file, it expands all the Mul* records out. At write time, the individual cell records are written, so the file gets slightly bigger. I think there's an entry in the POI bugzilla for the enhancement to get POI to coalesce cells into Mul records, but no-one seems to have volunteered to work on it yet...